# When flagging, requested to have link to duplicate

Tags: bug, feature-request, flagging

I wanted to flag two of the answers to [this](https://superuser.com/q/147027/82812) question as duplicates of the accepted answer, as they were later, and had less information (and thus serve no purpose).

For the flag (can't yet vote to delete) I wrote a custom reason of "Dupe Answer." I was then treated this this box:

[image]

This is silly. I am flagging as it is a duplicate *answer*, not question. Additionally, while for duplicate questions, the moderator that is reviewing the flag may have a hard time finding the "origonal" question, that is not the case with duplicate answers.

As such I think this is a bug (for having duplicate question as opposed to answer) and as a feature request/bug to remove it from the check on answer flags.

Comment: Did you try just putting a dupe link to the answer that was duplicated?

Comment: And if you want it more clear, prepend it with `Copied from`. But indeed, the filter probably shouldn't work for answer. Or they could introduce a duplicate answer flag, although that wouldn't be used much...

Comment: @nhinkle, I didn't try, just wanted to point out the bug.

Comment: @TomWijsman, anyway to know how many flags (as a percentage) are not an answer>

Comment: fair enough, just wondering. first time I've seen this

Comment: @soandos: Given that deleted answers are not accessible through the data dump or API only the developers can come up with such statistics.